# user.scope settings path changed after upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Hi I have develop a small app in c# (.net 4.0) that uses the LocalFileSettingsProvider Class to save and load settings for the user. But after the last upgrade last night I have notice that the url path

```
<Profile Directory>\<Company Name>\<App Name>_<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>\<Version>\user.config
```

changes after I run the upgraded application. What I believe is being changed is the `"<Evidence Type>_<Evidence Hash>"` part of the path. Since the last upgrade I have only change a few lines of code to fix a minor bug in my application and the application version. Everything else look the same so I am a little bit in the dark here. I have also tried to revert to an older version of the app and re-commit the changes again but the result was the same.

Does anyone have any clue why the above path is now being changed and causes the user settings not to get upgraded? Is the above behavior normal for the LocalFileSettingsProvider Class?

Under what circumstances does the above path get changed?

Any help is appreciated!

Regards

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.upgrade%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi I do upgrade after each new version but my problem now is that the path changes and the older settings are not found.